# WordPress / Elementor / Astra - how to set when a menu should be displayed as hamburger?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

I have a web site that has a fairly wide main menu of five items.  This works fine on a desktop display, and on a mobile device this changes to have the menu displayed as a hamburger menu.  However, on an iPad landscape display the full menu is displayed, messing up the UI.

In WordPress how and where do I set when a hamburger display should be used for a menu?

Also I've just noticed that when using an iPad in portrait mode, when I click on the hamburger menu nothing is displayed.

I'm using Elementor with the Astra theme.